# Converting decimal from LINQ query to Currency

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

Here is my LINQ Query:

```
GridView.DataSource = from it in DataContext.Items
    where it.ThingId == thing.ThingId
    select new
    {
        it.Something,
        it.SomethingElse,
        it.AnotherSomething,
        Currency = String.Format("{0:C}", it.Decimal.ToString()), 
        //^--This is the line that needs to be converted to currency, this doesn't work--^
    };
```

The `it.Decimal` is returning a decimal in the form `12345.00` and I need to convert that to `$12,345.00` when displayed in the gridview. What I have now doesn't work, because a LINQ Query won't recognize the `String.Format` function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the `ToString`:

```
Currency = String.Format("{0:C}", it.Decimal)
```

You can also use this form:

```
Currency = it.Decimal.ToString("C")
```

If you pass `it.Decimal.ToString()` as a parameter to `String.Format`, it will be handled as a string, not a decimal, so it won't be able to apply the currency format.

---

EDIT: ok, so you have another problem... Don't forget that a Linq to SQL (or Entity Framework) query is converted to SQL and executed by the database; the database doesn't know `String.Format`, so it can't be converted to SQL. You need to retrieve the "raw" result from the db, and then format it using Linq to Objects:

```
var query = from it in DataContext.Items
    where it.ThingId == thing.ThingId
    select new
    {
        it.Something,
        it.SomethingElse,
        it.AnotherSomething,
        it.Decimal
    };

GridView.DataSource = from it in query.AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
        it.Something,
        it.SomethingElse,
        it.AnotherSomething,
        Currency = it.Decimal.ToString("C")
    };
```

(Note the use of `AsEnumerable` to "switch" to Linq to Objects)

Another option would be to give the raw decimal value to the `GridView`, and set the column's `DataFormatString` property to "C"

Comment: When I go to databind, I get this error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: @Chris I get an error with that one: `No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: that works pefectly! Thanks! I thought it was implied that you can't execute methods in the LINQ query, based on my code above. I understand that, which is why I needed an alternative. And your's works perfectly! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the ToString() function to convert it to currency like this:

```
.ToString("c")
```

Comment: I've seen this as well as what I'm doing when I looked around the interwebs, but for some reason, this one causes an error. Apparently I'm not supposed to give .ToString() and argument?

Comment: Interesting.  I don't know what might be causing that.  You could just leave it in decimal in Linq and then format it when you display it.  I know that may not be what you're looking for, but it's kind of hard to tell what may be the problem there.  I've done this and have not problems with it.

Comment: Sorry...I didn't clarify...I'm trying to get this done so I can go home...you can't do stuff like that in LINQ queries...I thought that was implied by the code in my question. I guess not. Thank you though!